# Is there a way to access device browser data with xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-development, xamarin.essentials

I want a xamarin application to be able to access current browser data on the device. Xamarin.Essentials will give the platform and os being used, so knowing that is there a way (on ios for example) to access the browser data on the device? Example: what tabs are open

Comment: How this is C# question? "Can one app access data of another app on iOS/Android" does not sound like C# specific or yet requiring C# answer.

Comment: No.  This would be a security nightmare if an app could detect your browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

*Apple care about the security and privacy of user ver much* .It's **impossible** in iOS now .

From iOS file system , an iOS app operating within its own sandbox directory generally .

[image]

Although iOS can sharing data between iOS apps and app extensions , however that needs to configure in sahred App (Here is Safari in iOS).

> App Groups are the mechanism iOS uses to allow different apps to share data. If the applications have been properly configured with the correct entitlements and provisioning, they can access a shared directory outside of their normal iOS sandbox.

As far as I know , **Safari** not provides data api for other apps to use .

Reference documents :[File system access in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#sharing-data-between-ios-apps-and-app-extensions), [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)